# default cursor on jquery ui tabs

Tags: css, jquery-ui

The selected tab shows the caret when over the tab text. I'm trying to get the default arrow cursor over all tabs (the none selected tabs give me the hand). Not sure what css I need to set to make everything about tabs show the default cursor. I have the below but it doesn't change the cursor for none selected and selected tabs.

.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-default{cursor: default;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right rule, but you need to increase the specificity of your rule to override the jQuery UI CSS.

```
#tabs.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
    cursor:default;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3m6sxwde/)**

and there's always the often maligned option of using `!important`

Comment: ty. I'll get the hang of css eventually :)